# Inputting coordinates and point data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to QGIS, and I am currently using it for my uni dissertation which is focused on GIS based siting of windfarms/turbines in the Derbyshire Dales district of Derbyshire.

I have some GPS coordinates of windfarms in the regions and would like to add them to my map layer.

How do I do so?

Thus far i have used longitude and latitude data of the position of a windfarm from google earth 53.087346 -1.634774. I have saved the file as tab delimited and csv.

When selecting the tab delimited file in QGIS it gives me the error message crs was unidentified.

Comment: Is that the precise wording of the error message?  "cis was unidentified".

Comment: What CRS does your project use? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60432/which-crs-to-use-for-google-maps. You may have a project in EPSG: 27700, British National Grid

Comment: If you don't know about CRS then take a look at this short video from Karl Karlsson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vKNo23i8KI it may help

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273143/how-to-add-delimited-text-layer-in-qgis-3-0/273169#273169

Answer (score 1):

If you have GPS readings they come in EPSG 4326, latitude, longitude WGS84.

Answer (score 1):

As you have access to GoogleEarth;

1. Add Placemark (Pin) - Provide Latitude and Longitude in the New Placemark window.
2. Save it as KML file (`Save Place As...`)

Start QGIS;

3. Drag and drop the KML file to QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that QGIS doesn't understand how to read the latitude and longitude values that you are providing. 
Take a look here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html

Decimal degrees are just one way of defining a location in space.

QGIS probably doesn't know this however so you need to provide it a CRS. It depends, but your CRS is likely WGS84 if the data came from Google Earth, this should be the default CRS for a new project in QGIS but maybe yours differs. Check the above link to see if your settings match up.